# need to know purpose of disown command inside a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Below code pings a set of servers and checks is it up or down.

Im getting different sequence of output if i use and if i don't use "disown" command. can someone throw light on whats happening

111.111.111.229 is down. so there will be no "server up" output for that machine

Code with Disown

```
#set -vx
#!/bin/bash

check_server_status()
{
 printf "IP inside fun is $1 \n"
 ping -c 1 $1  > /dev/null
 [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo Server with IP $i is up
}


for i in 111.111.111.{229..230}
do
printf "IP is $i \n"
check_server_status $i & disown
done
exit
```

output

```
IP is 111.111.111.229
IP is 111.111.111.230
IP inside fun is 111.111.111.230
IP inside fun is 111.111.111.229
Server with IP 111.111.111.230 is up
```

Code with out Disown

```
#set -vx
#!/bin/bash

check_server_status()
{
 printf "IP inside fun is $1 \n"
 ping -c 1 $1  > /dev/null
 [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo Server with IP $i is up
}


for i in 111.111.111.{229..230}
do
printf "IP is $i \n"
check_server_status $i 
done
exit
```

output

```
IP is 111.111.111.229
IP inside fun is 111.111.111.229
IP is 111.111.111.230
IP inside fun is 111.111.111.230
Server with IP 111.111.111.230 is up
```

Comment: You are not getting different order because `disown` is missing, but because `&` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it without disown but with the `&` still at the end of that line?

I think you'll find that the difference is not caused by disown, but by that character. The ampersand tells the shell to put the command into the background and not wait for it, which means that both ping operations can occur in parallel. The timing is unpredictable, so it's entirely possible that the ping function you started first actually gets executed second.

Comment: Got it now Alex thanks.Will you be able to tell what is the role of disown command